# Open default ios contact list in react native app with multiple contacts select

Tags: ios, react-native, multi-select, react-native-contacts

I want to open default ios contacts list with multiple contact selection in react native. For that I tried react-native-contacts-wrapper package, it doesn't support multi-contact select. So I moved to react-native-contacts, which allows multiple contact select, but it doesn't give the **look and feel** of ios contact list.

Is there any package which has multiple contact select with default ios contact list UI?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement the design for it yourself, what I found that might be a starting point for you is:

https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select (Probably with a single section or without sections), bonus includes search.

or

https://github.com/tableflip/react-native-select-multiple

Edit: also found this that can be worth to try https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select

(Clarification, neither iOS or Android have native dialogs to select multiple contacts)